# ¿Por qué dos DropDownList cambian su valor si solo se le asigna a uno?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas a todos, estoy creando unos dropdowns para controlar horas y fechas en un aplicativo web (ASP.NET), cuando cargo mi formulario, al asignar los valores traídos desde la BDD, los dropdowns obtienen el mismo valor sin que yo lo indique.

```
string[] FecCr = (dt.Rows[0][3].ToString()).Split(' ');
string[] _FecCr = FecCr[1].Split(':');
string[] subIn = (FecCr[0].ToString()).Split('/');

string[] FecFn = (dt.Rows[0][4].ToString()).Split(' ');
string[] _FecFn = FecFn[1].Split(':');
string[] subFn = (FecFn[0].ToString()).Split('/');

txt_FecInicio.Text = FecCr[0].ToString();//fecha de inicio acta
ddlHoraInicio.Text = _FecCr[0].ToString(); //hora inicio
ddlMinutoInicio.Text = _FecCr[1].ToString(); //minuto inicio acta

txt_FecFin.Text = FecFn[0].ToString(); //fecha fin de acta
ddlHoraFin.Text = _FecFn[0].ToString(); //hora fin acta
ddlMinutoFin.Text = _FecFn[1].ToString(); //min fin acta
```

y este es el resultado: (a la captura incluí los valores que llegan en el DataTable)

[image: el error en cuestiòn]

y este es el resultado que espero, adicional-mente, pongo los campos con sus respectivos id

[image: así debería verse]

Cualquier sugerencia o ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias!

Edito:

Les adjunto también la sección de código HTML (el documento entero es muy extenso)

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><h5>Fecha inicio</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Hora</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Minutos</h5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FecInicio" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="elemento-requerido form-control" onpaste="return false" onkeypress="return soloback(event)" OnTextChanged="RevisarFechas" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txt_FecInicio" TargetControlID="txt_FecInicio"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHoraInicio" Cssclass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RevisarFechas"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMinutoInicio" Cssclass="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RevisarFechas"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><h5>Fecha fin</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Hora</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Minutos</h5></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FecFin" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control elemento-requerido" onpaste="return false" onkeypress="return soloback(event)" OnTextChanged="RevisarFechas" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="txt_FecFin" TargetControlID="txt_FecFin"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHoraFin" Cssclass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RevisarFechas"></asp:DropDownList></td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMinutoFin" Cssclass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RevisarFechas"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
```

El evento RevisarFechas es el siguiente:

```
private void RevisarFechas()
{
    if (txt_FecInicio.Text != "")
    {
        string[] FechIn = (txt_FecInicio.Text).Split('/');
        DateTime fecIn = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(FechIn[2]), Convert.ToInt32(FechIn[1]), Convert.ToInt32(FechIn[0]), Convert.ToInt32(ddlHoraInicio.Text), Convert.ToInt32(ddlMinutoInicio.Text), 0);
        if ((DateTime.Compare(fecIn, DateTime.Now)) < 0)
        {
            if (txt_FecInicio.Text != "" && txt_FecFin.Text != "" && ddlMinutoInicio.Text != "" && ddlMinutoFin.Text != "" && ddlHoraInicio.Text != "" && ddlHoraFin.Text != "")
            {
                string[] FechFn = (txt_FecFin.Text).Split('/');
                DateTime fecFn = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(FechFn[2]), Convert.ToInt32(FechFn[1]), Convert.ToInt32(FechFn[0]), Convert.ToInt32(ddlHoraFin.Text), Convert.ToInt32(ddlMinutoFin.Text), 0);
                if ((DateTime.Compare(fecFn, DateTime.Now)) < 0)
                {
                    int resultado = DateTime.Compare(fecIn, fecFn);
                    if (resultado < 0)
                    {
                        lblFechaInicio.Text = "";
                    }
                    else if (resultado == 0)
                    {
                        lblFechaInicio.Text = "La fecha y hora de inicio y finalización son coincidentes.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblFechaInicio.Text = "La fecha de inicio no puede ser superior a la fecha de finalización.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblFechaInicio.Text = "La fecha de finalización no puede ser superior a la del día de hoy.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblFechaInicio.Text = "Complete todos los campos.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblFechaInicio.Text = "La fecha de inicio no puede ser superior a la del día de hoy.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si los valores de los Items dentro de tus dropdown list los cargas desde un dataset, entonces no puedes asignarle el valor seleccionado a través de la propiedad `.Text` En este caso creo que tienes que usar el `.SelectedValue`

Comment: has usado algun tipo de evento? quizas estes usando la misma referencia para los dos y por eso al cambiar uno te cambia el otro.

Comment: no, utilizo un DataTable... DataTable dt = Actas_BRL.SelectTable(objAct, 5);

Comment: Veelicus, todo se ejecuta en el PageLoad

Comment: Usas el mismo datatable para rellenar ambos combos? si es asi, ahi tienes el problema

Comment: puedes añadir el código html de tu asp?

Comment: Por qué tendría problemas al usar el mismo DataTable? Ya lo he hecho y siempre me ha funcionado bien.

Miguel, espero ese fragmento sea suficiente.

Comment: Solo por darme el capricho a mi: Utiliza dos DataTables diferentes para rellenar los Comboboxes y me dices si te funciona :) Simplemente haz `this.comboBox2.DataSource = dt.Copy();` (siendo dt el datatable que usar para llenar las horas por ejemplo)

Comment: Compañero, no afectó en nada. Siguió teniendo el mismo comportamiento, aunque ya encontré la solución fue algo mas sencilla de lo que se pensaba... (la pongo como respuesta para que los que puedan llegar a tener el mismo error, sepan que es)

Comment: Bueno, es que yo no llenaba las opciones de ese modo, yo creaba las opciones con un for y luego asignaba el valor a cada DDL

Comment: Vale,es que comentaste que usabas un DataTable. Si lo has resuelto perfecto. Pero como ves, el error era por lo que te decia,usar la misma estructura de datos para rellenar el ddl :)

Comment: Si, en esencia tenías la razón...tal vez por eso pensé en revisar esa función. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta que error se encontraba en otra función que no pensé que influyera. Tengo una función que crea todas las opciones del DDL, pero antes estaba añadiendo el ListItem a todos los DDL que fueran de hora o minuto, y al parecer,eso era lo que generaba ese comportamiento en el aplicativo.

Finalmente creé un for para cada control.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            string op = i.ToString();
            if (i < 10)
            {
                op = "0" + i;
            }
            li.Text = op;
            li.Value = op;
            ddl.Items.Add(li);
        }
```